# Flask-login not working as expected

Tags: python, session, oauth, flask, flask-login

`Flask-login` appears not to "save user in session". On the `/login` handler, the user is logged in and remembered via `login_user(user, remember=True)`, but upon opening any other page, the user returned is the `AnonymousUser`, not the logged in user from `User` class.

Here is the simple user class with accompanying methods for getting the user from another class used for database storage.

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    # Flask-Login is technically able to support these.
    # We don't swing that way.
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def get(userid):
        print 'getuser instance'
        return User(find_user_by_username(userid))

    def get_id(self):
        return self.user.username

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.user.username

    def get_auth_token(self):
        print 'gettingtoken'
        data = [self.user.id, self.user.username]
        return login_serializer.dumps(data)
```

The methods for getting the user, and user loader are as follows:

```
def find_user_by_username(username):
    print 'find by find_user_by_username'
    i = TwitterUser.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if i is not None:
        print 'found user'
        return i
    print 'didnt found'
    return None

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    print "userloader"
    return User.get(userid)

@login_manager.token_loader
def token_load(token):
    print 'readingtoken'
    max_age = app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION"].total_seconds()
    data = login_serializer.loads(token, max_age=max_age)
    print 'data: ', data
    user = User.get(data[1])
    if user:
        return user
    return None
```

I don't need passwords for authentication, I use OAuth, so I would like to check the user token stored in the user table. I suspect that something is wrong with the `token_load()` or with the `get_auth_token()` methods.

Two sample routed I did to explain the behavior are:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    user = User.get('stackoverflow')
    print "login"
    if user.user is None:
        newUser = TwitterUser('stackoverflow', 'email@gmail.com', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'something', 'something')
        db.session.add(newUser)
        db.session.commit()
        print 'added user'
        return redirect('/login')
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    return str(current_user)

@app.route('/user')
def user():
    return str(current_user)
```

These debugging return values return, in the first case:

```
<User u'stackoverflow'>
```

and in the second case:

```
<flask_login.AnonymousUser object at 0x02D455F0>
```

So, basically, is is evident that although the  `login_user()` managed to log in the user and set the `current_user` as it should be, but when loading some other view, the `AnonymousUser` is returned as `current_user`.

One interesting thing, it might be important is that I never see the `gettingtoken` string, so I can't confirm the `token_load` function is being called at all.

I have opened another question regarding this, but upon further examination I think the issue is unrelated to the matter described there, thus the reasoning behind this question.

Comment: For kicks and giggles, check to see if `login_serializer.loads()` returns a correct user in the second view. I'm willing to bet that it doesn't.

Comment: I have some debug print statements there, and they are not appearing in the console, so I doubt that that portion of the code is even running. Regarding the token writing, I even tried doing `md5()` around the `data = [self.user.id, md5(self.user.username)]` followed by `return login_serializer.dumps(data)` so the user data is basically hashed, but still the same.

Answer (score 4):

For the people, who may find this fixing the same issue, maybe I'll save you some time.

Check your user_loader function very carefully, symbol by symbol with example in docs. Because mine looked like this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user (id_):
    User.query.get(int(id_))
```

And I just spent 5 hours finding this mistake, because I skimmed through it several times, and haven't seen anything wrong (it's missing `return` keyword).

Among other issues which may cause this problem are:

- Your User class does not implement required methods (is_authenticated and 3 others) or inherit UserMixin class
- You have some problems with saving cookies in your browser (they are not stored, or immediately deleted)
- You accidentally logging out user out right after the login, for example by redirecting to page, which sends request to /logout route

Comment: I can't believe I forgot the `return` keyword. Thank you, I had been pulling my hair over this, it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add these fields in the User model if you are inheriting from UserMixin.

1. is_authenticated
2. is_active
3. is_anonymous
4. get_id()

I hope your problem is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Comment: I believe it's optional so there shouldn't be a problem if they do. Presuming they use them in the right way

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it does work for me (with changes) - you must have done something wrong outside what you have shown here. In particular, `readingtoken` was output as expected, and `current_user` was the logged in user in `user` view.

In particular, check that you did install the login manager to the application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123123123'
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
login_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.secret_key)
```

and see that the plugin versions are proper; mine are

- Flask 0.10.1
- Flask-Login 0.2.11
- itsdangerous 0.24

Also, you might want to use the `TwitterUser` with `UserMixin` instead of wrapping 1 "user" object inside another.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I do have that method but forgot to include it in the comment. I mentioned it in the description above the code block that included the `get` custom method and the token loader, but forgot to copy it. So, its not that, I have the user loader.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are overriding the app.session_interface of Flask with a custom session interface.
Flask uses the flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface, and Flask-Login seems to depend on certain properties in it.

Might you by any chance be using MongoDB as your database and/or MongoEngine as the ODM? (It might happen with other app.session_interface overrides as well)
I had the exact same problem with token_load not being called, debugged it for about a day, only to find out that the problem was the MongoEngineSessionInterface that I used in the app.

Not exactly sure if it applies here, but in my case the problem was that Flask-Login performs a check in its code for 'user_id' being in the session, and when using MongoEngineSessionInterface it always is, so it never had to call my token loading handler.

Simply removing that session interface as a workaround worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I am not using MongoDB, I use SQLAlchemy with MySQL for database storage.  I checked some potential places, I do import `session` from `flask`, and from `flask_login` I use `LoginManager, login_required, login_user, current_user, logout_user`. Besides that, thres another importm `from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer` and those might be some causes for this. I kinda solved the issue by using session manually, but that limited my options and eliminated some options in the app. I will definitely check this in the following days to see will this help!